# symfony2 FOSUserBundle base:html.twig

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I would like to use the `FOSUserBundle`, but I didn't overwrite my `app/resource/base.html.twig` so I have not the view like in http://knpuniversity.com tutorial. Can you show me your `base.html.twig when` it's overwrited by the `FOSUserBundle`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your layout somewhere so just create a layout.html.twig in your UserBundle/Resources/view and then put there sth like that

```
{% extends 'SomeBundle::layoutyouwanttoverwrite.html.twig' %}

{% block content %}
    {% block fos_user_content %}{% endblock %}
{% endblock %}
```

I hope that helps :)

And don't forget to put

```
public function getParent() 
{
    return 'FOSUserBundle';
}
```

In your UserBundle class :)

Comment: no, i have this error

file_get_contents(C:\wamp\www\facebook\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle/Resources/views/Profiler/toolbar_js.html.twig) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /facebook/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Loader/Filesystem.php line 126


i dont understand this
C:\wamp\www\facebook\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle/Resources/views/Profiler/toolbar_js.html.twig

because I send my project on server

Comment: hmm, so this error is often shown as side effect of some other error. Can you see any other error?